# Prevent JavaScript to be refreshed every time the page is loaded

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var Value = new Date();
var min = Value.getHours();

setTimeout ("Timeout()", 1);

function Timeout ()
{
    for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("d")[i];
    x.innerHTML = (min + ":" + "0" );
    };
    min--;
    setTimeout ("Timeout()", 1000);
}

</script>
<p class="d"></p>
```

Now my problem is that every time I refresh the page the variable gets reset. Is there a way to set the variable once for a certain amount of time, so it doesn't get reset?
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into setting a cookie to store the current value of the variable?

Comment: What did you mean by refreshed? Did you mean getting from the server? or prevent running js code?

Comment: This is like asking why variables are reset when restarting native EXE programs (for example). 
Refreshing the page means re-executing the whole page, including javascript code. you can store the values you want to keep in LocalStorage or Cookies.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this. You could use cookies to save the variable - [see here for more info](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) and check upon the next request, if a cookie was set.

Other than that, you could also utilize URL parameters to retain state

```
location.hash = your_var;
```

And check upon the next request, if `location.hash` has been set. There are several other possibilities for that, I only showed you two ways to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Guess the easiest way would be using cookies, you can achieve that easily using jQuery cookie plugin, [this one for example](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), which makes the saving as easy as:

```
$.cookie("example", "foo");
```

and reading:

```
$.cookie("example")
```